# Given that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx\le M$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given that for a continuous $f$, $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx\le M$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ 
Then

i) $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ exists if $f\ge 0$

ii) $\int_{0}^{\infty} f$ exists if $f$ is differentiable

iii) $\int_{0}^{\infty} f$ exists if $f$ is differentiable and bounded

iv)$\int_{0}^{\infty} f$ exists.

for (ii) and (iii) (iv) take $f(x)=\sin x$ so (i) is only true?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  If $f \ge 0$, then $g_n = \int_0^n f(x) dx$ is monotonic and bounded above.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reproducing Andrew Salmon's comment above so that this does not go unanswered.

> Yes, you are correct. If $f\ge 0$, then $g_n=\int_0^n f(x)\ dx$ is
>   monotonic and bounded above.

(...which means the limit as $n$ goes to infinity exists, so the indefinite integral exists.)

Comment: what is community wiki by the way?

Comment: @TaxiDriver I'm not entirely sure. There's a guide to using it somewhere, but I can't find it. I use it whenever  I don't want to take credit for someone else's answer.